# How to resolve event log "all files are up-to-date" in Android Studios

Tags: java, android, android-studio, event-log

Having tried to add [This game](https://github.com/videogameboy76/frozenbubbleandroid) to my phone via Android Studio, while trying to build the project it throws in the event log "All files are up-to-date". I've looked through the program and it was built in eclipse, with no luck converting it to Android Studios.

I've tried to "import" some of the files with no luck.

other solutions I've tried with no luck are outlined in:

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35563157/tfs-all-files-are-up-to-date)

And

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649290/tfs-get-command-erroneously-returns-all-files-are-up-to-date)

Answer (score 0):

Are you clicking "Build APK" in the Build drop-down menu? If not, try that! [Here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/#reference) is a nice reference for building apps in Android Studio.

Comment: I don't have that as a choice in the "Build drop down menu" in the menu there only (build project, build module, recompile, rebuild project, generate ant build, and build artifacts) and the one that can be clicked return the same (Event log: "All files are up-to-date")

Comment: try "build artifacts"

Comment: The button isn't able to be clicked.

Comment: Oh I see the issue. In the build.xml file indicates an Ant build (Android Studio uses Gradle by default). If there is a way to build projects in Android Studio using Ant, I don't know it. But I'm sure someone else does. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

think it's an Eclipse IDE (`ant`) project ...

you'd need to import it to Android Studio (`gradle`), first.

managed to build the `Android.mk` with `ndkBuild`, after importing the project.

the `build.gradle` looks alike:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.jfedor.frozenbubble"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 26
        compileSdkVersion 26
        ndk {
            moduleName "modplug-1.0"
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path "src/main/cpp/Android.mk"
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jni.srcDirs = ["src/main/cpp"]
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
}
```

that `andmodplug_PlayerThread.h` needs to be dropped into the `libmodplug` directory, where the other headers reside (the import does not copy it, because it's in a completely unexpected location). also renamed directory `jni` to `cpp` and assigned that path to the main `sourceSet`.

Comment: Are you able to go through the process of this?

Comment: and another down-vote without the least reason ...for a proper answer.